# Вывести на экран элементы, значение которых совпадает с их порядковым номером в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Сейчас изучаю JavaScript, еще совсем чайник, наткнулся на данную задачу:

> Дан массив с числами. С помощью цикла выведите на экран все элементы, значение которых совпадает с их порядковым номером в массиве.

Вот моё решение:

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 6, 4];

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {

    let arrEl = arr[i];
    let arrIndex = arr.indexOf(i);

    if (arrEl == arrIndex) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Но, если я изменю массив на [0, 1, 2, 4, 4], то в данном случае функция не вернет в консоль цифру 4 и так, с любой цифрой, [0, 1, 3, 3, 4] - в дааном случае не вернет цифру 3, хотя порядковый номер в массиве равен - 3.

Подскажите где я допустил ошибку или что не учел. Спасибо.

Comment: `if (arr[i] === i)`

Comment: Для вашего способа и массива `[0, 1, 3, 3, 4]`. Пусть `i == 2`, тогда `arrEl == 3`, а `arrIndex == -1`, и следовательно `3 != -1`. Теперь пусть `i == 3`, тогда `arrEl == 3`, НО `arrIndex == 2` (`indexOf` ищет _первое_ вхождение), и следовательно `3 != 2`.

Comment: Понял ошибку, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принять начало порядкового номера за `0`, то тогда можно сильно упростить код, сравнивая очередной элемент массива с его индексом `i`:

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 6, 4];

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {

  let arrEl = arr[i];

  if (arrEl === i) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял, что из-за моей ошибки, создал лишнюю переменную )

Comment: @MaXiMuS в таком случае не забудьте отметить один из ответов как верный, чтобы закрыть данный вопрос :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4];

arr.forEach((el, index) => {
  if (el == index) console.log(el)
});
```

Comment: Еще практически не знаком с методами массивов, по этому оставлю правильным ответом предидущий ответ. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.filter((element, index) => element === index)
```

(4) [0, 1, 2, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Для расширения кругозора, без методов и коротко:

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 6, 4];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] !== i || console.log(i);
```